# REST endpoints don't fire

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing a simple REST service where registered users can post stuff.

Registration and authentication work fine, however, when I try sending `POST` or `GET` requests to any protected path, I see a 200 status code without anything in response body in Postman.

If needed, I can provide the whole source code, but I think the issue lies somewhere either in filter class or in the configuration class.

My configuration:

```java
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
        .and()
    .addFilterAfter(new JwtFilter(userService, jwtUtils), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/v1/register/**", "/api/v1/users/authenticate").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

My `JwtFilter` class:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final UserService userService;
    private final JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        var header = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(jwtUtils.Bearer)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        var jwt = header.replace(jwtUtils.Bearer, "");
        var username = jwtUtils.extractUsername(jwt);

        if (username == null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        var user = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if (!jwtUtils.validateToken(jwt, user) || !user.isEnabled()) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        var passwordAuthToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
        passwordAuthToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)); // implies that request should contain user details?
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(passwordAuthToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason to why you are not using the built in jwt features in spring security https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs? Could you show the response with headers, for example a screenshot Postman. However, I think you are missing a  `chain.doFilter(request, response);` in the last line of your method.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I copied this stuff from a video.

Comment: @sirkostya009 then that is your problem, please dont just copy stuff. Read documentation before asking on stack overflow. Do research

Comment: @dur calling `FilterChain` object at the end of the function did solve the problem. Huh, but I thought you actually don't need it there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dur mentioned in comments, problem was that I miss a `chain.doFilter(request, response);` line at the end of `doFilterInternal` function.

Now it should look like following:

```
var header = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

if (header == null || !header.startsWith(jwtUtils.Bearer)) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}

var jwt = header.replace(jwtUtils.Bearer, "");
var username = jwtUtils.extractUsername(jwt);

if (username == null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}

var user = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);

if (!jwtUtils.validateToken(jwt, user) || !user.isEnabled()) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}

var passwordAuthToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
passwordAuthToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)); // implies that request should contain user details?
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(passwordAuthToken);
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```